# Choosing a linear map $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is nonzero on half of a sequence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_m \in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$ be nonzero vectors.  Is it always possible to choose a linear map $f : (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f$ is nonzero on at least half of the $v_i$, i.e. such that

$$|\{\text{$i$ $|$ $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $f(v_i) \neq 0$}\}| \geq \frac{1}{2}m?$$

My guess is that the answer is yes; at the very least, it is true for $m=1$ and when the $v_i$ enumerate all of the nonzero vectors.

Comment: Please clarify, what is $\mathbb{Z}/2$?

Comment: It is the set of integers modulo $2$.

Comment: Why don't you write *in words* what you want in the body of the question? Desciphering an equation when a perfectly good English sentence might be considerably easier to understand is silly!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : Sure thing.  But isn't that a little pedantic?  The equation isn't all that complicated...

Comment: You are free to your opinion: I am also free not to be willing to try to parse it. I didn't. And you thereby lost a possible answerer!

Comment: I don't disagree with @Mariano's comment, but let me just add that this is a very nice question.  Where did it come from?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : It came up yesterday during tea.  I don't know where the person who asked it found it.  By the way, I'm pretty active on MO under a different name, but I decided that this question was better for MSe; I figured that someone who was good at contest type problems would be able to solve it (and I was right!).

Comment: @Monica: As PeteL.Clark said, it is a nice question and thank you for sharing with us. Just for clarification, I don't think I am "someone who was good at contest type problems", because contest type problems depressed me a lot in my high school days. :)

Comment: And I am someone who generally finds contest type problems quite boring (which is not to say that I know how to solve them).  Looking back at the comments, Monica got a less warm welcome than she should have: $\mathbb{Z}/2$ could only mean one thing (unlike $\mathbb{Z}_2$!) and upon reflection I *do* disagree with Mariano's comment.  I'm glad it turned out well in the end.

Comment: BTW: Laszlo Babai wrote (most of) a book called *Linear Algebra Methods in Combinatorics*.  To the best of my knowledge it was never really published, although copies circulated through the U of Chicago community (which is how I got one).  This area of mathematics is not particularly my cup of tea, so believe me especially when I say that the book is amazing and wonderful.  This problem has a similar flavor to some of the content in there (and maybe it is actually in there; I don't have my copy close at hand).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : Thanks!  This experience definitely provides me another data point concerning using gendered names on the internet (I usually don't).  It also appears that one can order the Babai book from U of C; see http://www.cs.uchicago.edu/research/publications/combinatorics

Comment: @Monica, If you are implying that my comment was even slightly motivated, caused, or anything, because you are woman, I find that **EXTREMELY** offensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is **true** and let us prove it by induction on $n$.

Denote $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}:=\mathbb{Z}_2:=\{0,1\}$. When $n=1$, the statement is clearly true. Now assume that when $n\le n_0$, the statement is true for every $m\ge 1$,  and let us show the statement is true for $n:=n_0+1$ and every $m\ge 1$.

Consider  $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n$ as $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n-1}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and denote by $P$ and $Q$ the projections of $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n$ to its first $n-1$ coordinates and its last coordinate respectively, i.e.
$$P: (\mathbb{Z}_2)^n\mapsto (\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n-1},\quad(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}),$$
and
$$Q: (\mathbb{Z}_2)^n\mapsto \mathbb{Z}_2,\quad(a_1,\dots,a_n)\mapsto a_n.$$

Up to a rearrangement of $v_1,\dots,v_m$, we may assume that there exists $0\le m'\le m$, such that  $Qv_i\ne 0$ if and only if $m'<i\le m$. If $m'=0$, simply choose $f=Q$ and we are done, so let us assume that $m'\ge 1$. By definition, $Pv_1,\dots,Pv_{m'}\ne 0$. By the induction assumption on $n$, there exists a linear function $g:(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n-1}\to \mathbb{Z}_2$, such that 
$$|\{ 1\le i\le m' \mid g(P v_i) \neq 0\}| \ge \frac{1}{2}m'.\tag{1}$$
For $j=0,1$, define
$$f_j:(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n\to \mathbb{Z}_2,\quad v\mapsto g(Pv)+j\cdot Qv.\tag{2}$$
By definition, for $j=0,1$, $f_j$ is linear and $f_j(v_i)=g(P v_i)$ when $1\le m\le m'$. Then by $(1)$, for both $j=0$ and $j=1$,
$$|\{ 1\le i\le m' \mid f_j(v_i) \neq 0\}| \ge \frac{1}{2}m'.\tag{3}$$
If $m'=m$, then we are done. Otherwise, note that by $(2)$ and the choice of $m'$, for $j=0,1$,
$$f_j(v_i)=0 \iff g(Pv_i)=1-j\iff f_{1-j}(v_i)=1,\quad \forall\, m'<i\le m.$$
It follows that
$$|\{ m'< i\le m \mid f_0(v_i) \neq 0\}|+|\{ m'< i\le m \mid f_1(v_i) \neq 0\}|=m-m'.\tag{4}$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$, we can conclude that the statement is true for either $f=f_0$ or $f=f_1$, which completes the proof.

---

**Remark:** Thanks to PeteL.Clark's nice question in the comment, I realized that the conclusion can be generalized to arbitrary finite field with the same argument as above.

> **Claim**: Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field of $q$ elements and let $v_1,\dots,v_m$ be nonzero vectors in $(\mathbb{F}_q)^n$. Then
>   there exists a linear function $f:(\mathbb{F}_q)^n\to\mathbb{F}_q$,
>   such that $$|\{1\le i\le m\mid f(v_i)\ne 0\}|\ge\frac{(q-1)m}{q}.\tag{5}$$

**Sketch of Proof:**
Define projections $P:(\mathbb{F}_q)^n\to (\mathbb{F}_q)^{n-1}$, $Q:(\mathbb{F}_q)^n\to\mathbb{F}_q$ similarly. Define $m'$ and rearrange $v_1,\dots,v_m$ similarly. By induction, we may assume that there exists a linear function $g:(\mathbb{F}_q)^{n-1}\to\mathbb{F}_q$, such that for $f_j=g\circ P+j\cdot Q$, $0\le j<q$, 
$$|\{1\le i\le m'\mid f_j(v_i)\ne 0\}|\ge\frac{(q-1)m'}{q}.\tag{6}$$
By definition of $m'$ and $f_j$, for every $m'<i\le m$, $f_0(v_i),\dots, f_{q-1}(v_i)$ are pairwise different, so one and only one of them is $0$. It follows that for some $0\le j<q$,
$$|\{m'< i\le m\mid f_j(v_i)\ne 0\}|\ge\frac{(q-1)(m-m')}{q}.\tag{7}$$
$(5)$ follows from $(6)$ and $(7)$ for $f=f_j$.

Comment: This is just lovely.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Thank you! The question itself is lovely.

Comment: How does this generalize to other finite fields, I wonder?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: A simple observation based on this argument could show that for finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, a lower bound is $\frac{(q-1)m}{q}$. Sketch of proof: we can define $f_j$, $0\le j\le q-1$ similarly as in $(2)$. By induction, we can assume that $(3)$ holds when $\frac{m'}{2}$ is replaced by $\frac{(q-1)m'}{q}$. When $i>m'$, $f_j(v_i)$ are pairwise different, so exactly only one of them is $0$. Then we can conclude that there exists $0\le j\le q-1$, such that $|\{m'<i\le m:f_j(v_i)\ne 0\}|\ge\frac{(q-1)(m-m')}{q}$, which completes the induction.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Sorry, please ignore my first reply and see the current one.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I updated my answer by adding discussion of the finite field case. Thank you for your nice question!

Comment: @Landscape: No, thank *you*...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

My coauthors and I needed this result recently (to prove something about pseudo-Anosov dilatations), and I was googling to see if it was known.  I'm amazed that it was asked here so recently!

I'm answering now to record a short alternative proof that we found.  I'll prove the same more general result that Landscape proved, namely:

**Claim** : Let $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_m \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$ be nonzero vectors (not necessarily distinct).  Then there
exists a linear map $f : \mathbb{F}_q^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q$ such that $f(\vec{v}_i) = 1$ for at least $\frac{q-1}{q}$
of the $\vec{v}_i$, i.e. such that $\{\text{$i$ $|$ $1 \leq i \leq m$, $f(\vec{v}_i) \neq 0$}\}$ has cardinality at least $\frac{q-1}{q}m$.

**Proof** : Let $\Omega$ be the probability space consisting of all linear maps from $\mathbb{F}_q^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q$, each given
equal probability.  Let $\mathcal{X} : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the random variable that takes $f \in \Omega$ to the
cardinality of the set $\{\text{$i$ $|$ $1 \leq i \leq m$, $f(\vec{v}_i) \neq 0$}\}$.  We will prove that the expected value $E(\mathcal{X})$ of $\mathcal{X}$
is $\frac{q-1}{q} m$, which clearly implies that there exists *some* element $f \in \Omega$ such that $\mathcal{X}(f) \geq \frac{q-1}{q} m$.

To prove the desired claim, for $1 \leq i \leq m$ let $\mathcal{X}_i : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the random variable that
takes $f \in \Omega$ to $1$ if $f(\vec{v}_i) \neq 0$ and to $0$ if $f(\vec{v}_i) = 0$.  Viewing $\vec{v}_i$ as an element of the double dual
$(\mathbb{F}_q^n)^{\ast \ast}$, the kernel of $\vec{v}_i$ consists of exactly $\frac{1}{q}$ of the elements of $(\mathbb{F}_q^n)^{\ast}$.  This
implies $E(\mathcal{X}_i) = \frac{q-1}{q}$.  Using linearity of expectation (which recall does not require that the random
variables be independent), we get that
$$E(\mathcal{X}) = E(\sum_{i=1}^m \mathcal{X}_i) = \sum_{i=1}^m E(\mathcal{X}_i) = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{q-1}{q} = \frac{q-1}{q} m,$$
as desired.